# How to show hide two image loop 4 times use jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, hide, show

My HTML:

```
<div class="luck">
  <div class="image1"></div>
  <div class="image2"></div>
  <div class="image3"></div>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```js
var 
    delay = 0,
    $ele = $(".luck > div");

$ele.hide();

for(var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
    $ele.eq(i).show();
}
```

My CSS:

```css
.luck {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.luck > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}

.image1 {
  background: red;
}

.image2 {
  background: green;
}

.image3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

Now I have 3 div : image1 , image2 , image3.

I want it run :

The first : image1 is show , next image2 is show

Again 1 : image1 is show , next image2 is show

Again 2 : image1 is show , next image2 is show

Again 3 : image1 is show , next image2 is show

It loop 4 times , then image3 is show , the progress is end .

Please help me by use jQuery

This is my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/u76r9wc2/

Comment: I could not understand where is your image progress.

Comment: I'm sorry , Image in my localhost,  I make 3 div for example of 3 image

Comment: i don't quite understand.  is there also a hide for those `image`s?

Comment: @roullie , I'm sorry , my english is bad

Comment: probably not what you wanted.  but check this https://jsfiddle.net/roullie666/u76r9wc2/2/

Comment: @roullie I want the progress is run follow my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u76r9wc2/3/

Comment: @roullie
It's work find , thank you very much (y)

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/u76r9wc2/5/ do you want like this?

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya
Thank you so much , This question done (y)

Comment: @DhiaTN Thank you , I will remember this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below one...This is what you required?

```
<div class="luck">
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
    <div class="image3"></div>
</div>
<style>
  .luck {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
  }

  .luck > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
  }

  .image1 {
    background: red;
  }

  .image2 {
    background: green;
  }

  .image3 {
    background: blue;
  }

</style> 

<script>
  var 
    itr = 0,
    delay = 500,
    $ele = $(".luck > div");

  $ele.hide();

  /*
  for(var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
    $ele.eq(i).show();
  }
  */
  show_repeat(0);
  function show_repeat(i){
    $($ele).eq(i).show(delay, function(){
       itr++;
       if(itr == 8){
          $($ele).eq(2).show(delay);
       } else if(itr % 2 == 0){
          $($ele).eq(1).hide();
          show_repeat(0);
       } else {
          $($ele).eq(0).hide();
          show_repeat(1);
       }
    });
  }     
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u76r9wc2/1/

Comment: I was clicked , but The number not change and show "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with recursion.

```js
var $ele = $(".luck > div");
var iter=8;
$ele.hide();
showImg(0);
function showImg(i){
 iter--;
  if(iter<0)
  {
   $ele.eq(2).show();
    return;
  }
 if(i<=1)
  {
  $ele.eq(i).show();  
    setTimeout(function(){ showImg(i+1); }, 1000);  
  }
  else
  {
   $ele.hide();
   showImg(0);
  }
 
}
```

```css
.luck {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.luck > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}

.image1 {
  background: red;
}

.image2 {
  background: green;
}

.image3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="luck">
  <div class="image1"></div>
  <div class="image2"></div>
  <div class="image3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VuHaoTran if match answer to your question then please vote up...!

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya : I was clicked on arrow (This answer is useful) , But I don't know why the number not change , but I will try vote for you any way I can . Thanks

Comment: @VuHaoTran you don't have a enough raputation for vote up&down i add some raputation try now..!

Comment: @VuHaoTran at least 15 raputation required for vote and you have a 18 raputation try now...!

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya wow , I was clicked , the number was change , thank you so much :D